# Apply scikit learn transformations to larger than memory datasets with dask and dask-ml?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, dask

I've been toying around with `dask` for the past month or so and its been very useful. I'm using `dask` with a ~30 million record dataset with ~12 fields (2 text, the rest are float) for purposes of analyzing/improving an ensemble of various models. What I'd like to do is apply a [box cox transformation](http://www.statisticshowto.com/box-cox-transformation) to the numerical data.

I've been looking into `dask-ml` and there are builtin support for similar preprocessing steps, like the `MinMaxScaler` or  `StandardScaler`

**It doesn't appear that the boxcox method is implemented within dask-ml, so I'm curious if it is possible to apply the scikit-learn transformer?**

In the meantime I am mapping this boxcox function i wrote to the respective fields, but I know the `scikit-learn` transformer optimizes the lambda value - which my function does not.

```
def boxcox(x,lam=1e-8):
    if lam == 0:
        y = da.log(x)
    else:
        y = ( da.power(x, lam) - 1.) / lam
    return y

data_boxcox = {}
for col in numeric_cols:
    data_boxcox["{col}_bc".format(col=col)] = dg[col].map(
        lambda x: boxcox(x, lam=-1e-8),meta=(('boxcox', 'i8')))
...
df = df.assign(field1_bc  = data_boxcox["field1_bc"])
df = df.assign(field2_bc = data_boxcox["field2_bc"])
...
df = Client.persist(df)
```

Any suggestions on how to better implement the Box Cox transformation or improve the `dask` code are much appreciated.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you problem is. Is the code to slow or are you experiencing crashes due to running out of memory, or something different?

Comment: I recommend raising an issue at https://github.com/dask/dask-ml/issues/new asking about PowerTransformer

Comment: In sklearn that's `PowerTransformer` and I am not seeing it in Dask API.